# Reason for shorter bond between sulphur and oxygen?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, molecular-orbital-theory, resonance, valence-bond-theory

I recently came across this sentence in my textbook:

> the bonds between sulphur and oxygen in oxides of sulphur ($\ce{SO2}$ and $\ce{SO3}$) are much shorter than might be expected for a single bond.

[image: so2]

[image: bonding][image: so3]

I feel it could be due to partial double bond character due to resonance.

And the same textbook gives another explanation:

> In these molecules, in addition to normal π bond, a π bond is also
>   formed by the sidewise overlap of a filled 2p orbital of oxygen with a
>   vacant 3d orbital on the sulphur). This is called pπ - dπ bond and
>   results in bringing the two atoms closer and thus accounts for shorter
>   bond length of $\ce{S-O}$ bond.

The reason provided in the textbook (as mentioned above) is definitely untrue and incorrect

Because of reasons mentioned in these posts

[Why is the bond order in the SO₃ molecule 1.33 and not 2?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29101/why-is-the-bond-order-in-the-so%e2%82%83-molecule-1-33-and-not-2)
.
[Hybridization of sulfur in sulfur dioxide](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/51168/hybridization-of-sulfur-in-sulfur-dioxide])

Please provide a explaination for the same (the title question).

Comment: Well, maybe this is because they are _not_ single bonds?

Comment: Please cite the sources for the quotes and images you use, even (or especially) it they are from of own network.

Comment: "Which is definitely untrue and incorrect" Why do you think so?

Comment: @Karl  “That is thoroughly incorrect. chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/51168/… chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29101/… – Mithoron”

Comment: Please explain this (in one or two scentences) in your question. It's not obvious.

Comment: Your resonance formulas show double bonds, and single bonds *with a charge separation*.

Answer (score 3):

If you would consider it more carefully, you would see that the bond order in SO2 and SO3 are, respectively, 1.5 and 4/3. This means that they are shorter than a single bond of sulphur and oxygen.